# Build pipeline for a large project

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, kentico

I should start with saying that this is my first time really using Azure Dev Ops and setting up pipelines, so I apologize if I don’t understand things right away and seem a little slow haha

I have a large Kentico CMS project (It’s a .NET C# Website project) that I’m trying to setup a build pipeline for but unfortunately because it is so big, the 30 minute timeout always cancels the build process and I’m not too sure what to do to speed it up.

Below are my available pools to choose from. I don’t think we have any self hosted pools at the moment.

[image]

This is all for my job. I unfortunately don’t have full access to our Azure Dev Ops or our Azure Portal but there are some settings and configurations that I think I should be able to do. If there are some settings or adjustments that I don’t have access to, I can pass that information along to our IT and Platform Services department.

This is what my build report looks like.

[image]

And these are the error messages that I'm getting.

```
##[Error 1]
The agent has received a shutdown signal. This can happen when the agent service is stopped, or a manually started agent is canceled. 

##[Error 2]
The job exceeded the maximum allowed time of 00:30:00 and was stopped. Please visit  for more information.
```

Please let me know what other information I should provide.

Comment: As of now, you are good to go right? If you face any issues during setup a build pipeline then you can include that in your question.[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started-designer?view=vsts&tabs=new-nav#create-a-build-pipeline) you can get the quickstart for creating a build pipeline.Moreover you can configure the [timeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=vsts&tabs=designer#task-control-options) of the task, by default timeout is 0 which means it will wait for infinite

Comment: No I'm not good, the build fails every time because of the time out. Even though it's set to 0 it only lasts 30 minutes. I'll add a screenshot of what it looks like.

Comment: How long does it take to build the entire solution from scratch on your dev system? Are you using WebSite or WebApplication-style projects? For reference; we use Azure DevOps for all projects, including large ones and none of them takes more than 10 minutes to build from start to finish. Including package restore, front-end pipeline etc Using private agents, we usually manage to keep the build below 5 minutes.

Comment: @MarnixvanValen on my dev system it also takes almost 30 minutes. Kentico CMS is quite big. 17,418 files and that's after excluding A LOT of stuff. I have thought of just not building the project but that kind of defeats the purpose of it all. I was also hoping that each successive build would be faster because it wouldn't have to rebuild the entire project, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a self-hosted agent and that got things working. Unfortunately the size of the repo still makes the build and release very long. But I guess that will have to do for now.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the solution is more a kind of pricing options

Please have a look at [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/53fd7ce9-fd61-4535-b364-f0d4848e5d4d/release-management-build-agent-timeout?forum=TFService)

**Free Tier**

240 minutes (shared with Build)
30-minutes maximum single job duration

**Paid Tier**

$40 / Agent
360 minute maximum single job duration

[Refer here for the detailed pricing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/licensing/concurrent-jobs-vsts?view=vsts)